# Is there any way of using an object type in @property-read and "declare" its attributes?

Tags: php, annotations, phpstorm, phpdoc

I want to add a type of object in `@property-read` and also be able to access its attributes with PhpStorm suggestions.

Here's what I would like to do:

```php
/**
* @property-read object{type: string, schema: string} $request_schema
* @property-read object{type: string, schema: string} $response_schema
*/
class ConfigApiRoutesSchema extends BaseSchema
{
...
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I want to access the attributes type and schema, like this:

```php
$configApiRoutesSchema = new ConfigApiRoutesSchema();
$configApiRoutesSchema->request_schema->type // Here's the problem, type is not suggested
$configApiRoutesSchema->request_schema->schema // schema is also not suggested
```

This is exactly what I need, but unfortunately this doesn't work for some reason. One solution is to create two classes and specify them as types:

```php
/**
* @property-read string $type
* @property-read string $schema
*/
class RequestSchema {}
    
/**
* @property-read string $type
* @property-read string $schema
*/
class ResponseSchema {}
    

    
/**
* @property-read RequestSchema $request_schema
* @property-read ResponseSchema $response_schema
* @
*/
class ConfigApiRoutesSchema extends BaseSchema {}
```

Now PhpStorm suggests both schema and type.

But it doesn't seem correct, since `RequestSchema` and `ResponseSchema` won't actually be used. So I wonder if there's any way of using annotation with objects without having to create a class to suggest its attributes.

Thank you.

Comment: Sadly no. It's in JavaScript you can describe custom type using JSDoc only. But not in PHP / PHPDoc -- PHPDoc has no such syntax (search for PSR-5 and PSR-19). I personally unaware of such way (to declare multiple/complex properties of the object) without actually declaring a class somewhere (even if it's for IDE eyes only). Maybe tools like Psalm/phan/PHPStan can do something like that, but not PhpStorm (at very least not yet).

Comment: Usually, when you see that IDE offers a completion for result of a some dynamic function (e.g. fields in PDO query results) it's done by some plugin that sees what table you are querying, sees separate table structure and can offer such fields there. Same with other cases where `stdClass` instance can be involved (e.g. parsing XML or JSON into plain object).

Answer (score 0):

Altho it is possible to specify the shape of arrays, for objects it is not possible to do so (yet). Such a syntax would have been be specified in [PSR-5](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) and [PSR-19](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md), but this is not the case.

In the same manner it is not possible to specify the properties of a returned plain object from a method with the `@return object` annotion.

Apparently the syntax is [supported by Psalm](https://psalm.dev/r/6ae8ebd551), but not in PhpStorm (at very least not yet).

Currently there is [a public proposal on the PhpStorm YouTrack board](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-66396/Support-object-shape-generic-object-property-declaration). You might want to upvote that issue to increase it's chance of being included in the next PhpStorm version.